# RxJava2 question: How Zip handles error when calling multiple services in parallel?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

Suppose we have 3 services, employeeTitle, employeeName,
employeeLocation. If all services three services throw error
employeeTitle, employeeName and employeeLocation will service only
throw 1 error? According to the documentation this should be the
behavior is this correct? What happens if only employeeTitle throws
error and the other services are successful? As per my understanding
if employeeTitle throws an exception then zip will still throw 1
exception only and this exception will be employeeTitle's service
error. Am I in the right track?

-In my code below, I am expecting the zip error to come in the first onErrorResumeNext inside getEmployeeInfo()

```
Single<Model> getCompositeEmployeeInfo(){ 
  return Single.zip(
     api.employeeTitle()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
     api.employeeName()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
     api.employeeLocation()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
     new Function3<EmployeeTitle, EmployeeName, EmployeeLocation>() {

     @public Model apply(EmployeeTitle empTitle, EmployeeName empName,
                         EmployeeLocation empLocation){
       //some logic
     }

Single<Model2> getEmployeeInfo(){  
return getCompositeEmployeeInfo()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable-> { 
           return Single.error(throwable}//I am expecting only 1 error(if 
            //more than one error is thrown) from 
            //zip, either employeeTitle, employeeName or employeeLocation.
         )
         .flatMap(model -> {
                 //some logic
           return getEmployeePreference();
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                       return Single.error(throwable);
                    })
                   .flatMap(employeePreference -> {
                      //some logic
                      return Single.just(result);
           });  } }
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but for the sake of performance you should really change your backend/api to provide all employee data at once, so you'd only need one request instead of three.

Comment: @Ridcully I just put this as an example. This is not the actualy api services.

Answer (score 1):

The "reactive contract" states that there can only be one terminating condition, either `onError` or `onComplete`. When you combine multiple observer chains with `zip()`, termination conditions from the three observer chains are combined into one.

If an error is raised by the first observer chain, there is still a possibility that errors can be raised in the other two. However, only the first error is emitted by the `zip()` operator. In addition, since the observer chains run on separate threads, there will be a race to see which error gets reported; it is non-deterministic.

Errors that are raised in an observer chain **after** the chain has terminated, or when there is no longer a way to handle the error down-stream, are passed to a global handler.